# Imitate browser zoom with transform scale CSS breaking the tooltip and popover position

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

In angular I am using transform: scale(0.8) to imitate the browser zoom in functionality. zoom in is working fine but the angular material tooltip and popover are not coming at their respective position they are shifted left and up. without transform tooltip and popup are coming at their proper position.
Is there any way I can fix this.
Thanks